# Send information to PHP file using ajax and load this file to a div using .load()?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my ajax script:

```
var cid = $(this).data('cid');
var sendData = { canidtoset: cid };

$.ajax({
    url: '/functions/cv_showinformation.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: sendData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        $('#can-viewer .cv--informationtab .infotab--inner')
        .load("/functions/cv_showinformation.php");

    }
});
```

It gets the value of an attribute called data-cid from an clicked element. This value should be send to an PHP-Script that gets included into a div after the element was clicked. The PHP-Script:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['canidtoset'])){

        $canid = $_POST['canidtoset'];
        echo $canid;

    } else {

        echo "Something went wrong";

    }

?>
```

In the end it should show the value from the attribute in the div. But it doesn't even gets included so I believe the data wasn't set. Where the hella is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType: json` means the data coming from your server is expected to be json (you're sending plain text).

the second issue is that your `.ajax` call should be all you need. the `.load` call is accomplishing the same thing without your passed value.

the easiest solution should be to change your dataType to `html`

```
var cid = $(this).data('cid');
var sendData = { canidtoset: cid }

$.ajax({
    url: '/functions/cv_showinformation.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: sendData,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {

        $('#can-viewer .cv--informationtab .infotab--inner').html(data);

    }
});
```

or, you can pass post data to `.load` as well. just make sure you replace your `.ajax` call with it instead of nesting it inside the success callback.

```
$('#can-viewer .cv--informationtab .infotab--inner')
    .load("/functions/cv_showinformation.php", { 
        canidtoset: $(this).data('cid') 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you alot. The second method works just fine tho.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use .load() then we can do like this to avoid errors

```
var cid = $(this).data('cid');
var sendData = { canidtoset: cid };

$.ajax({
    url: '/functions/cv_showinformation.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: sendData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        $('#can-viewer').load('test.php?canidtoset='+ data);

    }
});



<div id='can-viewer'></div>
```

/functions/cv_showinformation.php :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['canidtoset'])){
        $canid = $_REQUEST['canidtoset'];
        echo $canid;

    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong";

    }
```